# Getting Unit Code Coverage as 0% in SonarQube with Jacoco Build from another Jenkins Machine

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using a Jenkins machine to get a build. By using jacoco i asm showing the Unit Coverage on Sonarqube.
But recently it is showing 0 %.

In Build log from jenkins shows "*There are test Failures*"

Right now i am considering the issue is because of Test failures.

But wheather there could be any other Problems.

Please help me out.

Comment: hi @potame ,i am not able to attach or write whole log, but if u require any specific part of the build i can try.

Comment: Please edit the original post instead of adding comments. :)